# getting no errors with curl and also dont get any response

Tags: php, curl, netflix

am trying to login to netflix using php curl but i get no response at all or errors.here is my code

```
$handle = curl_init();


    $url = "https://www.netflix.com/ke-en/login";

// Array with the fields names and values.
// The field names should match the field names in the form.

    $postData = array(
        'userLoginId' => 'Lady',
        'password' => 'Gaga',
        'submit' => 'ok'
    );

    curl_setopt_array($handle,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            // Enable the post response.
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            // The data to transfer with the response.
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        )
    );

    $data = curl_exec($handle);
    echo curl_error($handle);
    echo curl_errno($handle);
    curl_close($handle);

    echo $data;
```

the error i get is 0 and i saw that it means it is successfull

Comment: Netflix killed their API in 2014 for a reason. They probably don't want to allow anyone to do anything via scripts so I suggest abandoning this task. Debugging wise, Add `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to your script. It is possible that you are getting cookies or redirect requests in header instead of data.